# How to create feather wings and attach them on sphere?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I want to create a wing to attach it on a sphere in blender. How can this be done? Should i use grease pencil to achieve this or use other tools? I am new to the blender.

I want this in 3d and very similar to the attached image.[image]

Comment: I am not quite sure with your image of "wing on a cube". Do you want to attach a 3D, realistic of wing or a 2D, cartoon-like wing or something else.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Your queston is quite unclear at the moment. I would suggest to add more information about what you have and what you are not able to achieve. Why would you use the grease pencil?

Comment: I have updated my question to be more accurate and explanatory. Sorry for confusion. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a very basic modeling project, what exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your reference image, here is a quick solution:

Under the *Properties* panel in the 3D viewport, enable *Background Images*, then click *Add Image*. Pressing Open will bring you to a file browser; here, select your winged ball image.
[image: Image highlighting Background Images panel.]

Switch to orthographic view (5 on the numpad), than press (on the numpad) 7.
Add a plane, then go into edit mode. Select all of the points but one and delete them. Move the point to the edge of the wing in the picture. Then, pressing E (for extrude) make a line around the wing. After getting to the end, select both end points and press F to fill in a line.

[image: The last two points.]

The line is finished along the whole wing:

[image: Finished line image.]

Now that the whole outline is created, press F to fill the area with a face.
Exit "Top Orthographic" view. Press E while the whole outline is selected to extrude the outline and add depth to the wing.

Here is the finished wing:
[image: Image of the finished wing.]

Here is what I made with this:
[image: My render]

### Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer to a not so great question

Comment: @time passes: please answer this question if you are free https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98910/how-to-create-and-design-hoops-net-and-attach-ot-to-a-hoop