# How to create and design hoops net and attach ot to a hoop?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I wanted to add the torus object and attach net on the torus object in blender. I am not sure how to make a circular net and attach it to a torus object.

Comment: This answer would be pretty huge. Mostly tutorial like and this isn't pretty welcome here. I can make an overview of methods I have used but you will need to search for the details. Check my result here: https://imgur.com/ABgqweQ You can also ask specified question about this animation, this will be better suited for BSE.

Comment: @LukeD : Can i get overview of methods?

Comment: @LukeD: Ding!! Ding!! Anybody home? Reminder :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Final:

[image: final]

### Net/Rope:

[image: rope]

I've made the net from [Bezier Curve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/index.html) just by extruding vertices and tweaking handles. I've added [Mirror](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html) and [Array](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html) modifiers at the beginning to have constant overview of my whole shape. Array count should be even to number of hooks on you rim. Also **Relative Offset** is a bit smaller than 1 to overlap lines, this will give fake knots on rope.

At the end you will need to add [Curve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/curve.html) modifier with selected **Bezier Circle** from the Rim shape.

Next add **Bevel** to our net:

[image: bevel]

Now you will need to scale a bit on X axis our whole **Bezier Curve** (net) because adding **Bevel** will add also a little offset to it.

When everything is looking as you want duplicate this shape and move it to another layer - just in case.

Last thing before going further is to [convert Bezier Curve (net) to mesh.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2917/how-can-curves-be-converted-to-meshes)

### Cloth:

Add **Cylinder** with exact same radius and height as our net/rim and some **Loop Cuts**.

[image: cylinder_1]

Add [Surface Deform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/surface_deform.html) modifier to our net select created **Cylinder** and hit **Bind**.

[image: bind]

Scale/Move/Tweak **Cylinder** with **Proportional Editing** to get basic net shape. Our net will follow this modifications due to **Surface Deform** modifier.

[image: cylinder_deform]

Add **Vertex Group** to our **Cylinder** and **Assign** to it top **Edge Loop**.

[image: vertex_group]

Add [Cloth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/cloth/index.html) sim to **Cylinder** and tweak settings. I encourage you to test different values for different cloth behavior.

[image: cloth]

Now you can hide **Cylinder**.

### Final thoughts and blend file:

I haven't used any complicated methods, all links provided should explain every step and if not - any question should be answered here or with many tutorials around the web. Also with provided blend file you should easily figure it out.

> Remember to **Apply Scale and Rotation** to meshes.

**Blend file:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the best answer. I downloaded blend file and I tried to animate by adding sphere and applying rigid body in it. However sphere is not passing through the net. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a sphere with rigid body in my blend file. Set frame to 0 and play animation then.

Answer (score -1):

This is a quick and rough method to create the net.

1. First add a plane object. Subdivide it several times.
2. Add decimate modifier and choose undivide, iteration 1 to make subdivision diagonal.
3. Then add wireframe modifier to create net. Add subdivision surface modifier and choose simple.
4. Then add a bezier circle and add curve modifier to the net and choose the bezier circle as object. Now experiment with choosing axes in curve modifier until you get right. Lastly change the size of beziercircle accordingly.
5. Add cloth physics to the net object. Select one side (choose the correct side by expermenting) of the net plane and add to vertex group. Choose that vertex group in pinning under cloth physics and run simulation.

you can get the blend file from here.
[image]

Hope it helped.

Comment: @K B: Thanks for your reply, but its not a perfect one. I need something like https://imgur.com/ABgqweQ as posted by @LukeD .

Comment: it can be made perfect by applying all the modifiers except the cloth and making necessary changes to the mesh i.e. deleting upper and lower side bands,snaping and joining left and right  sides.