# How do I make a face (or other model) extrude out of a plane like The Frighteners poster?

Tags: shape-keys, shrinkwrap

[image: Example01]
[Example02](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIYS2LYVmDQ)

I've tried doing this with a subdivided plane and shrinkwrapping it to a model, then applying it as a shape-key. Unfortunately, I tend to get a lot of jagged edges and spikes in the plane when the face is extending out - and often, the resemblance to the original model is quite faint.

Does anybody have any tips or suggestions for making this look good? Could really do with the advice, have been hacking at this for some time now. =/

Best regards,

--Rev

Comment: if you drop a plane with Physics > Cloth (for example Cotton) on a shape it will give this kind of effect, but I'm not sure how to make it work the other way around, i.e. shape moving towards the cloth, it looks like the shape goes through the cloth instead of just deforming it like in the first solution. Is it for an animation or just an image?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114134/pulling-a-net-tight and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125116/how-to-do-vaccuum-sealed-pack-modeling-in-blender/