# How can I make my cloth sim show tight folds?

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation, collision

I'm trying to achieve visuals like the following:
[image]
Unfortunately, this is the best I've got so far...
[image]
I'm using the 'pinning with hooks' method seen halfway down [this page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114134/pulling-a-net-tight) - I'd let the cloth drape itself naturally over the figure (which looks pretty close to my target!), but I want to have the objects below the membrane to rotate and move. Hence the pinning.

If there's anybody out there with experience on tight cloth folds, I'd really appreciate some notes.