# Why are my hooks and sewing not holding my cloth in place?

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I’m trying to solve the problem detailed in

[How can I make my cloth sim show tight folds?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144733/how-can-i-make-my-cloth-sim-show-tight-folds)

but I’ve run into an issue where the hooks in my cloth are not holding it in place when my monkey head presses against it.

Ideally, it should be working similarly to this:

[image]

…but instead, I’m getting this behaviour…
[0001-0080.mkv (13.4 KB)](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/vt6SJefU5aibfOH4oUoSbPcDogj.mkv)
…where the cloth is torn from the pinned points and blows away from the pressing object.

Can anybody explain why the cloth is not pinning correctly? Absolutely baffled here.

Blend-File: [image]

Demonstration of Vertex Group:
[image]

Comment: Pretty sure there is... Hmm. I'll add an image to the initial post to demonstrate that I have a Vertex Group set up...

Comment: yes sorry my bad... oh ok so you solved it  ;)

Comment: Please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) if you want to provide files for us to check. Random file sharing services won't keep them up long enough.

Comment: @metaphor_set - Pasteall.org isn't considered good enough? It's by http://www.graphicall.org/ and the files would last 5 months. I'll definitely consider Blend Exchange in future, thank you.

Comment: @cegaton - Yes, this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @ReverendSpeed - "files would last 5 months." is way too short, considering that Blender Stack Exchange is a Q&A site where questions/answers are still useful in a couple of years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I had created Vertex Groups, I had failed to **assign** specific vertices to the groups. 
[image]