# How can i conform a mesh to a plane?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a sheet of atoms that id like to conform to a wavy plane. ive tried shrink wrap but doesnt help. iam trying to achieve this affect

(https://500px.com/photo/136629141/crystallized-carbon-hexagonal-system-by-kiyoshi-takahase-segundo?ctx_page=1&from=search&ctx_type=photos&ctx_q=carbon).

Here is what i am working with so far (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gA5S.jpg)

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in image uploader for adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Also, http://take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with taking better screenshots.

Comment: Surface Deform Modifier is what you want to use. Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98910/how-to-create-and-design-hoops-net-and-attach-ot-to-a-hoop/99074#99074